# Is there any way that we could achieve sending larger files more than 10 gb using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I need to send an email along with a large attachment.

I tried using an AWS lambda function along with SES functionality, and my files are stored in S3 with sizes varying between 1MB to 1GB.

Comment: I suppose you tried embedding them in the email? You should just include links to the attachments and you're good to go.

Comment: You've indicated files of size 1MB, 1GB, and "more than 10GB". That's quite a range. If you really have to solve it for all sizes then simply host the files in S3 and email links to the files. Use pre-signed, time-limited unless these are public files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really isn't advisable to send large attachments in emails like this. It would be much more practical to include a link to this file so that it can be downloaded by the user you're sending the email to. S3 allows you to configure permissions settings so that you can ensure this user can download the file. Consider taking that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using pre-signed URLs to S3 buckets that are granted a limited time until expiry. [Pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). Or perhaps through an IAM route. [Bucket access to specific roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/)